# kendoUi grid disable column

Tags: jquery-ui, kendo-ui

I would like to disable column on databound based on the role security.

I am currently able to hide it not disable as the following but i have no idea how to disable it. Please advise thank you

```
function OnDataBound_ProductGrid() {

        if ("@ViewBag.Role" == 'Admin') {
            var grid = $("#Product").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.hideColumn(0);

        }
    }


@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
  .Name("Grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
     columns.Template(ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'/> ");
     columns.Bound(r => r.RouteName);
  })
  .Events(events =>ev.DataBouns("OnDataBound_ProductGrid"))
)
```

Comment: try disabling all controls inside that row like grid._data[0].find('').attr('disabled','disabled');

Comment: How you looking with your issue any progress ?

Comment: Hi Bobby, instead disable it i hide the column. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Antony:

Following property must be set to false:

```
  model: {
        fields: {
            ProductID: {
                //this field will not be editable (default value is true)
                editable: false
            }
        }
    }
```

And in your scenario you should be able to do following:

```
function OnDataBound_ProductGrid() {
        if ("@ViewBag.Role" == 'Admin') {
            var grid = $("#Product").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.datasource.fields.ProductId.editable = false;

        }
    }
```

Wrapping/using the admin role condition around the grid definition would also do the job:

```
    if ("@ViewBag.Role" == 'Admin') { 
       InnitGrid(false);
    }
    else
    {
       InnitGrid(true);
    }

    function InnitGrid(isEditable) {
       $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                       dataSource: {
                                   model: {
                                        fields: {
                                            ProductID: {
                                                editable: isEditable
 // or just replace isEditable with ("@ViewBag.Role" == 'Admin')
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                } 
                            }); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the field to `editable: false` on the data source.

Comment: i understand that but it is not what i want to achieve since is the checkbox and it depends on value of ViewBag.Role

Comment: Are you using the ASP MVC helpers to generate the grid? Could you attach a snippet showing how you are declaring the grid and explaining the issue your having?

Comment: Hi Antony, i have added my grid in the post above

Comment: Hi, Try changing your template to: `"<input type='checkbox' " + @ViewBag.Role == "Admin" ? "onclick='return false;'" : string.Empty + " class='checkbox'/> "`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that returns true or false, in depends what do you need.

```
columns.Bound(r => r.RouteName).Editable("isNotEditable");

function isNotEditable() {
    return false;
}
```